# "IDLE quit unexpectedly" when opening any Python file on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

[image: screenshot of error message]

I was working on my hw for tkinter. Then it stopped poping up the game it normally does when I hit run. I then decided to restart my computer thinking it would correct itself, but in the end now my apple computer wont even let me open up any python files. It just slowly opens them then closes immediately and gives me the error in the picture. Is there something I can do to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: I can add a video also if you want to see what happens before this error shows up! Thanks!

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: Until this issue is resolved, i recommend using vsvode (free) or jupyter notebook (free)

Comment: Start with the simplest thing.  Using Terminal (bash), can you start Python 3.8, in interactive mode, by entering `python3.8` at the `$ ` prompt.  If so, try `import tkinter`.  If that works, try `import idlelib.idle`.

Comment: Next time -- pasting the text of the error into your question itself _as text_ is a lot more useful than a screenshot. Text can be copied-and-pasted, can be searched, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if it is because of Apple. If I'm correct the Mac's come with Python 2.7 installed. You downloaded Python 3.8, and now those two versions of Python might be interfering with one another. Here is a link to using a virtual environment you can install it, and Python 3 in it so it doesn't mix with Python 2 (https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2018/11/working-with-virtual-environment-for-django-project.html). You can ignore the Django commands if you don't want to download Django. I haven't used Mac in awhile so I don't if there is a way you can control PATH variables on Mac's like I can with Windows. You could also download VSCode(free), Atom(free), Sublime(free, but will ask for donation) or any other code editor, and that'll fix your problem too.

Comment: Thank you I tried to do it and I may not have done it right for sure I am still trying to learn python and everything, but I will bring it up to my professor when I see him and see if it works for him!

Comment: That's a good plan! Good luck with your study's!